# Knockout - How to setup Computed properties for child and parent as same time?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a Collection of items that I would like to display the Total as well as individual Percentage of each item. The problem seems to be that I need a reference of parent object when computing the total. So I figured I'll define a computed getTotal for the Collection and a percentage for the item.

```
    function Collection() {
    var self = this;
    self.parts = ko.observableArray();
    self.getTotal = ko.computed(function() {
        var total = self.parts.length;
        return total;
    });
}

function Part(amount, parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.amount = ko.observable(amount);
    self.parent = parent;

    self.percentage = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.amount() / self.parent.getTotal();
    });
}

var partsData = [40, 50, 30];
var collection = new Collection();
for (var i = 0; i < partsData.length; ++i) {
    collection.parts.push(new Part(partsData[i], collection));
}

ko.applyBindings(collection);
```

And my HTML is

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: parts">
    <li>
        <p data-bind="text: amount"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: percentage"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However the Collection.parts is always empty. For some reason push it not triggering the items to be recalculated.

Also is this the right way for doing this? I could now figure out how I could simultaneously create an observableArray in the Collection while giving each child item a reference to the parent object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Your getTotal is supposed to return sum of amounts, not number of parts, right?
2. Your don't have to push elements to parts one by one. You can do collection.parts($.map([40, 50, 30], function(el){return new Part(el, collection);});) 
   (I use jQuery.map here)
3. In general I think percentage doesn't belong to Part, since then it has to be passed a collection, which is bad (unnecessary dependency). I would do it this way instead:

> ```
> function ViewModel() {
>     var self = this;
>     self.parts = ko.observableArray([]);
>     self.total = ko.computed(function(){
>         var s = 0;
>         $.each(self.parts(), function(i, el){s += el.amount();});
>         return s;
>     });
> }
>
> function Part(amount){
>     this.amount = ko.observable(amount);
> }
>
> $(function() {
>     var view = new ViewModel();
>     var parts = $.map([40, 50, 30], function(el){return new Part(el);});
>     view.parts(parts);
>     ko.applyBindings(view);
> });
> ```

Html:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: parts()">
    <li>
        <p data-bind="text: amount"></p>
        <p data-bind="text: amount() / $root.total()"></p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This will work fine.  I think that it is an okay choice to discretely represent the percentage on the Part object rather than calculating it in the view.  The way that you were doing it was fine.  In fact, you can even remove `self.parent` and just use `parent` from the arguments directly in your computed observable, as it will be included in the closure created by the function you pass to your computed observable.

Comment: I agree the initial code is fine, but if all you need is to show a percentage I would rather not introduce additional dependency between Part and Collection. It may be useful for some other stuff that is not part of the question though.

Comment: The reason I put put Percentage on the Part is because they will grow with a whole bunch of properties and functions. Eventually I plan to create Javascript models that will mimic my object model and it kind of makes sense. I think I missed putting () on my properties in the computed function and that broke it. Full credit to Roman.

Comment: Is there any way you can pull the `amount() / $root.total()` into the `Part` view model, in case the logic gets more complex and hard to put in the data-bind?  Can a computed depend on another computed?